# gridview issue when trying to get element from a row

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have a gridview which successfully binds to the database and gets all data. Now I have added a link button in one of the coloumns which does this:

```
GridViewRow grow = gvInbox.SelectedRow;            
DataRow dr = ((DataTable)this.gvInbox.DataSource).Rows[grow.DataItemIndex];
int MessageId = (int)dr["MessageId"];
Response.Write(MessageId);
```

Basically I am trying to get the datarow and get a `MessageID`. However the second line from above gives me `outofbound` exception.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your typecasting is slightly off...  You need to get the entire object that represents the data source...

```
yours... ((DataTable)this.gvInbox.DataSource).

should be (DataTable)(this.gvInbox.DataSource).
```

So you are typecasting the "this.gvInbox.DataSource" which is the datatable, then getting the .Rows[ ] reference from that.

Otherwise, its interpreting your typecasting like this.

```
((DataTable)(this).gvInbox.DataSource).
```

Comment: @user554134, what errors.. re-post.  It could be that its expecting a type-case of (DataRowView) and not (DataTable) as you are expecting.

Comment: With your syntax I get following "build" error, I never got a build error with my syntax: Error 3 'object' does not contain a definition for 'Rows' and no extension method 'Rows' accepting a first argument of type 'object' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) C:\Documents and Settings\admin\Desktop\car\Phase_2\tissot\tissot4\Mailbox.aspx.cs 284 63 tissot4

Comment: I would put a breakpoint at your "grow" object line, and run to that point.  Then in your watch window, play around with the settings / typecasting of each element you THINK is wrong before allowing it to continue with the DataRow process.  Then make applicable changes.

Comment: Do you know whether selectedrow is passed to the onclick of link button located on the gridview?

Comment: That may give the ordinal row of the dataview used to display the records.  Get into data row for that and get whatever "KEY" you need for subsequent action.

Answer (score 0):

A better way is to have your ID as DataKey in your GridView markup:

```
DataKeyNames="MessageId"
```

Then in your code behind you can reference it:

```
if(gvInbox.SelectedIndex > -1)
    MessageId = (int) gvInbox.DataKeys[gvInbox.SelectedIndex].Value;
```

Keep in mind that the DataTable will not be there on a postback. So to get data "out" of a GridView cell that is not a DataKey you see code like:

```
gvInbox.Rows[gvInbox.SelectedIndex].Cells[4].Text
```

Comment: Then nothing is selected.  You might also make use of if(gvInbox[gvInbox.SelectedIndex].RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)

Comment: Hmmm, I have this code in a linkbutton which is in gridview itself!

Comment: Clicking the linkbutton doesn't make the row selected. You want something like e.Row.RowIndex or e.RowIndex or e.NewEditIndex... depending on what you are doing.